# Coqide does not see global clipboard in wsl

Tags: clipboard, wsl-2, coqide

Ubuntu 21.10 under wsl2 in windows 10 successfully shares global clipboard content (for example, in nano or emacs) but coqide (8.12.0, installed through apt) does not.

I could not find any mention of clipboard in the configuration, nor in my local coqiderc file.

There is something called [CoqIDEWishes](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/CoqIDEWishes) at github coq repository but I could not find anything about it there either.

Is this a common problem or specific to my setup? Can I repair it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after installing `gpaste` (through apt).

Not sure what happened, most likely my Ubuntu only had some kind of "standard" clipboard handler which did not suffice for `gtk+` on which coqide seemingly relies.